# Filter log by text?

Tags: android, shell, adb, logcat, dalvik

I am using `adb shell logcat -v time filename` command programmatically to store logs into a file on an android device.

There are some internal logs for memory releasing activities which are stored under " dalvikvm " tag. (See the logs below). I don't have any problem with these logs but due to these logs, the log file gets heavier.
So my concern is reduce logs which have `GC_CONCURRENT freed` or `WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC` text in it.

I also tried to reduce logs by using it's tag, but it removes all logs related to that tag. I don't want to loose required tags under same tag name. I just don't want the logs which have `GC_CONCURRENT freed` or `WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC` text in it.

Is there any way or any adb command to resolve this problem. Thanks in advance.

```
04-18 01:02:53.644: D/dalvikvm(4302): GC_CONCURRENT freed 511K, 21% free 4106K/5192K, paused 5ms+1ms, total 19ms  
04-18 01:02:53.644: D/dalvikvm(4302): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 6ms  
04-18 01:02:53.684: D/dalvikvm(4302): GC_CONCURRENT freed 512K, 21% free 4106K/5192K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 15ms  
04-18 01:02:53.684: D/dalvikvm(4302): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 6ms  
04-18 01:02:53.724: D/dalvikvm(4302): GC_CONCURRENT freed 512K, 21% free 4106K/5192K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 16ms  
04-18 01:02:53.724: D/dalvikvm(4302): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 6ms  
04-18 01:02:53.764: D/dalvikvm(4302): GC_CONCURRENT freed 512K, 21% free 4106K/5192K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 16ms  
04-18 01:02:53.764: D/dalvikvm(4302): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 7ms
```

**EDIT**

I am using 
`adb shell logcat -v time | grep -v \"GC_CONCURRENT\\|WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC\" > " + filename` command.
It was working when I gave `filename` as my computer's local path.
But when I tried same with android device `/data/data/packagename/filename.txt`, it was not working.
It says that `bash: /data/data/packagename/filename.txt : No such file or directory` Can anybody suggest solution for that.

Comment: Recent releases have a `grep` which *may* (or may not?) be complete enough to to do negative matches with -v and accept multiple strings with \| - ie, grep -v "CG_CONCURRENT\|CONCURRENT_GC".  But if you are capturing into Java code anyway, you can just do your filtering there with the .contains() method of a String, discarding any line which matches.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that you can use host side utilities with the output from logcat. I would recommend using grep. In particular, with it's -v/--invert-match option.

```
adb logcat | grep -v "GC_CONCURRENT\|WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC" > filename
```

Comment: this command actually filter unwanted log
`grep -v "GC_CONCURRENT\|WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC" `

Answer (score -1):

The command to print specific logs using tag names. `*:S` which dont read logs related to `GC_CONCURRENT freed` and `WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC`

**Syntax**

```
 adb logcat TAG_NAME:PRIORITY
```

Below line displays only logs with `ActivityManager`, `MY_CUSTOM_TAG`.. tags

`adb logcat ActivityManager:I MY_CUSTOM_TAG:D ANOTHER_CUST_TAG:D *:S`

> S — Silent (highest priority, on which nothing is ever printed)

For more information visit Official Docs

1. [Android Debug Bridge](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html)
2. [Reading and Writing Logs](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html)

**UPDATED** Missed dumping to file.

Dump to file

```
`adb  logcat -d ActivityManager:I MY_CUSTOM_TAG:D ANOTHER_CUST_TAG:D *:S > filename.txt`
```

Comment: __Hope got Negative point after executing the above command and not got the output which the question needs : ) ....__